# Issue with Spartacus Storefront Setup

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Currently I have Setup Spartacus Storefront with **SAP Commerce 2005 Patch Level 6** on Local with a B2C generated accelerator in other words I have used ant modulegen to generate a new Storefront using yaccelerator template.

I am able to see the Electronic store up and running successfully on both custom JSP storefront and on Spartacus as well.

Now I am trying to create a new custom commerce webservice extension using the **ycommercewebservice** template. The problem I am facing is during Server Startup. The issue appears to stem out from **cmsocc** extension. Internally **cmsocc** has dependency on **commercewebservices** extension. As both **ycommercewebservices** and **commercewebservice** extension being one and the same the **EHCache** is facing some problem because of this. **Error Log is available on SAP Q&A Section please find [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13230762/issue-with-spartacus-storefront-setup.html).**

The other way I can think of resolving this issue temporarily is by cloning cmsocc extension and replace the dependency from commercewebservices to my custom extension which is generated using ycommercewebservices template but not sure if this is the right way to resolve the Issue or will this even workout in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838084/cx-media-cx-carousel-not-emitting-data

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this issue is not related to Spartacus. You might need to try other support channels for help.

Having said that, if you are intending to work with a Spartacus storefront, you may find the following documentation helpful:

- Installing SAP Commerce Cloud 2005 for use with Spartacus: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/
- Building the Spartacus Storefront Using 3.x Libraries: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/